# c++ call delegate from unmanaged code in a different thread

Tags: c++, delegates, unmanaged, managed

[Apologies in advance. I've read several postings both here and codeproject.com on this topic, but I'm still missing something.]

I have a notification framework (analogous to Events) as part of a legacy system written in unmanaged C++.  I also have a mixed-mode DLL with managed classes exposing legacy functionality to the managed world.

The CacheControlNotification class is a manage bridge class intended to translate the unamanged events to managed events.  It contains an unmanaged NativeCcmBridge class which is registered in the legacy framework to receive the unmanaged messages.  The NativeCcmBridge marshals the data to a managed type and passes it up to the CacheControlNotification where it dispatched to interested managed parties.

GetDelegateForFunctionPointer() is throwing NotSupportedException:  Delegates cannot be marshaled from native code into a domain other than their home domain.

The callbacks occur in threads originating in the native code.  The exception leads me to believe my solution is fundamentally flawed.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Robert

```
public delegate void OnNotifyHandler ( ManagedCallbackMessage^ );

//
// Native class to marshal callback to managed code.   Callbacks
// in the native world are registered via an "ANativeHandler" type.
//
class NativeCcmBridge : public ANativeHandler
{
    private:
        //
        // Pointer to the managed delegate
        //
        IntPtr m_callbackPtr;


    public:
        NativeCcmBridge ( OnNotifyHandler^ callback )
        {
            m_callbackPtr = Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(callback);
        }

        //
        // Provide implementation for pure virtual native handler
        //
        virtual void OnNotify (NativeCallbackMsg& nativeCallbackMsg)
        {
            // Convert the native message to a managed message
            ManagedCallbackMessage^ msg = new ManagedCallbackMessage( nativeCallbackMsg );

            // Now push the managed message via the delegate
            // throws NotSupportedException:  Delegates cannot be marshaled from native code into a domain other than their home domain.
            OnNotifyHandler^ callback = (OnNotifyHandler^)Marshal::GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(m_callbackPtr, OnNotifyHandler::typeid);
            callback( msg );
        }

};

//
// Managed Class to receive marshalled messages and 
// reissue in managed world.
//
public ref class CacheControlNotification
{
    public:
        CacheControlNotification()
        {
            m_callback = (OnNotifyHandler^) Delegate::CreateDelegate( OnNotifyHandler::typeid, this, "RaiseNotification" );
            m_bridge = new NativeCcmBridge( m_callback );

            // Register m_bridge the native mechanism
        }

        virtual ~CacheControlNotification () { this->!CacheControlNotification(); }
        !CacheControlNotification ()
        {
            delete m_bridge;
            m_bridge = nullptr;
        }

        event OnNotifyHandler^ OnNotify;

    protected:
        NativeCcmBridge* m_bridge;
        pin_ptr<OnNotifyHandler^> m_callback;

        void RaiseNotification ( CacheControlMessage^ msg )
        {
            OnNotify( msg );
        }
};
```

Comment: It is complaining about crossing an AppDomain boundary.  There isn't any evidence in your code of you creating an AppDomain.  Not sure where to go next, get code loaded in the primary domain, I guess.

Comment: The mixed-mode DLL (legacy framework) is included implicitly by a web application.  The initialization code runs in IIS via Application_Start in Global.asax.  The callbacks occur in threads created by the native code, but running under w3wp.exe.  I don't set up AppDomains, but I presume that IIS does.  Is this my problem?

Comment: Confirmed: the root of my problem is callbacks have a different AppDomain.  I reimplemented the solution using a static method in the callback rather than an instance method.  The NativeCcmBridge calls a static method on the managed CacheControlNotification class (no more delegate).  The original setup was done in a w3wp AppDomain; the callback occurs in DefaultDomain.